# How to detect if my recyclerview skips frames on scroll?

Tags: android, performance, android-recyclerview

My app has `recyclerView`. It scrolls smoothly on newer devices, but not so smoothly on older devices. I would like to disable some visual features, if some jank is there during scroll.

Is there a way to detect if `recyclerView` is experiencing jank during scroll?

Comment: You could probably disable those features for those old devices.

Comment: @JawadLeWywadi How do I know, if my app is running on those old devices, was the question.

Comment: Override the `onDraw` and compute how many fps you get for every second, IF the FPS is less than 30FPS then triggers a method call.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer** I have not tried this practically, this is just an idea.

- Get time at the time current position load.
- Get time at next position load
- Check that difference in those device where you feel that smooth.
- Set the benchmark for them and set your callback as required.